# Sharepoint sp2010 _Layouts mapped folder

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have a solution which can be deployed for SharePoint 2007 and SharePoint 2010. There are common files like .css files and images. When I am deploying solution for SP2010 I use mapped folder (_Layouts). And this folder have to copy my files to the server. The point is that I don't want to copy the same files to this folder. And I add them as a link. But Visual Studio does not want to copy files to destination folder.[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've resolved this issue. Just removed the links and added real files.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand you correctly, you want to deploy linked files.  This is not just a SharePoint limitation, but a Visual Studio limitation with web projects.  I believe the same limitation exists for SharePoint projects.  Please refer to the following link:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/665257/